# Choosing between Google Maps API v1 and v2

Tags: android, google-maps

In the middle of developing an Android app, I have taken Google Map android v1  have fetched the API key and added in the Xml and its displaying. My doubt is that v2 is now available and I have found in Google search that v1 APIkey providing will be stopped from March 3rd. So for now if I create with v1 will it be working in froyo to Jelly Bean after March 3rd.

Since v2 will support new version API level 17 and doesn't support in lower version which doesn't have OpenGl so if I create an app with v1 will it be fine to support from API level 7 to 17 ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not go with v2 already?

Comment: Yes I tried and it was awesome but it supports new version with graphics supported mobile device right? I need to reach large audience that is why in a doubt.

Comment: I exactly don't know the api level, but it supports above 8..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Will I be given opportunity to edit API key after March 3rd ?
```

***No***

```
if I create with v1 will it be working in froyo to Jelly Bean after March 3rd.
```

***Yes***

> It's better to go with Google Maps Api V2 instead of V1, because **no
>   new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However,
>   apps using v1 will continue to work on devices**.

Comment: I have got your context, you stated - It's better to go with Google Maps Api V2 instead of V1. But will it support at least from GingerBread onwards (Since large audience in Api L -10) so I can blindly choose v2 ?

Comment: Yes.I have made on Api Level 8

Comment: Great [Tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/)

Comment: The tutorial has it all. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Both APIs being very different in their design, it's a lot of work changing from one to the other. 
The only restriction with v2 is Android 2.3 and OpenGL ES 2.0, which is, according to Android dashbord, 90% for Android 2.3 as of 1st February, and 92% for opengl 2.0 as for 1st October.

I would therefore recommend you to start direct with v2.

v1 is a "working" API but has serious design problems, whereas v2 is a bit more restrictive, because it's much more optimized. (Most optimizations that you had to do on v1, you don't need to do them anymore on v2)