# Minimal Android API level to run Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have developed a mobile application that uses Google Maps Android API v1, and I plan to port it to the recent Google Maps Android API v2, as recommended by Google.

However, my application also targets Android 2.1 devices, and I cannot figure out whether the v2 Maps will run on such devices. I have found some reference suggesting that v2 should work with API level 8 and 10 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15011895/881731), [here](http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/12/google-rolls-out-android-maps-api-v2/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266014/881731)), provided that OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported by the mobile device, but nothing about API level 7.

My question is therefore: What is the minimum Android API level to run Google Maps Android API v2?

TIA!

Comment: Really guys, the question here is a bit more obvious than all that and it remains unanswered.. what would be the right approach if I wanna use the google maps api in android 2.1 and keep forward compatibility (like having my 2.1 app to run on 4.0.4 and keep the little map widget showing) .. is there any way?

Answer (score 13):

The Maps API are bundled with Google Play services and are compatible with Android 2.2 and higher. All devices with Android 8 API level support OpenGL 2.0, so devices with Android 2.1 version can't support Google Maps v2. You can check in the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api).

Comment: Note, though, that not all Android 2.2/2.3 devices have the ability to get the Play Services Framework, particularly those devices that never received the Play Store and are stuck with the old Android Market. Android 3.0+ should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

It'a API Level 8 (Froyo), because of the Play Services dependency.

Also take care that if you are using API levels 8 - 10 you need to use SupportMapFragment with the Android Support Library: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html , because fragments were only added in API level 11.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are trying in Android Emulator,

or,

you are trying with Tablet with don't have GPS Feature, Try with GPS enabled device, it should work properly

Comment: Sure, but what is the minimal API level that is officially stated by Google?

Comment: From "api level 1" you can use Google Location features, Prefer the package and see the class, you can notice yourself.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html

Comment: Following your link, I read that "The Google Maps Android APIs [...] are available on any device with the Google Play Store running Android 2.2 or higher, through Google Play services." So, should I conclude that API level 7 (i.e. Android 2.1) is not supported by Google Android Maps v2? Sorry, but the explanations from Google are definitely not clear...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As beni said, it works with Android 2.2 and higher version. But you need the android support library for 2.x versions seeing that it use fragments...