# Why google maps api v2 not working on api 8 and lower?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm develop app with **google maps api v2** from **google play service** and i'ts work fine .but when i try to run my app on api level 8 device.(xperia arc/old device) it is not loaded and crashed.
but on higher api's device it's works fine(like: s4,note3,s5).

I get the information about my location like this:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    //Get location info
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    String country = list.get(0).getCountryName();
    String city = list.get(0).getLocality();
    String street = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"country: "+country+"\nCity: "+city+"\nAddress: "+street, 2000).show();
```

logcat error:

```
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bis.work/com.bis.work.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.bibas.workclock.MainActivity.map(MainActivity.java:1890)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at com.bibas.workclock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:150)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
05-19 00:17:11.876: E/AndroidRuntime(2201):     ... 11 more
```

how can i fix it? 
thank's :)

Comment: Check this post, maybe can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024040/minimal-android-api-level-to-run-google-maps-android-api-v2

Comment: API level 8 is Android 2.2 - do you in fact mean API level 10 which would be Android 2.3.3?

Comment: Yeah sorry ... I meant the older version

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Google Play Services for Froyo` which is now separate from `Google Play Services` if you need to support older versions. still `Google Play Services for Froyo` will work on newer versions too so you do not need 2 separate app builds though.

See: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> Note: Google Play services 4.0.30 (released November 2013) and newer
>   versions require Android 2.3 or higher. If your app supports Android
>   2.2, you can continue development with the Google Play services SDK, but must instead install Google Play services for Froyo from the SDK
>   Manager.

Comment: I tried to delete the "Google Play Services-lib" and replace it with the"Google Play Services for Froyo" but now i can't import the "import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;"

Comment: you can explain this for me more specific?

Comment: @user3453502 Unfortunately, Google Play Services for Froyo does not include the Mobile Ads SDK.

Comment: @user3453502 They do not support it within one package. Period :) Most likely due to some platform specific code that they want out of main package (basically because Android 2.2 is just 1% of the market and declining

Comment: I have lots of my application users with older versions and I have to decipher how one can incorporate support for all versions. sorry about my english (google translate :) )